# Visual Differences in Google Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

I just moved over to Ubuntu yesterday. Yesterday everything seemed to look fine in terms of Google Chrome, but today everything is all Windows-XP styled. Text boxes don't pop out, it looks like I went back in time to 2008. I think I must have changed some setting.

What my Chrome looks like now.. (Please note the navigation bar and it's flat 1-D appearance.

[image: Notice navigation bar ontop]

But this is what I'm used to. Any way I can switch back to this look?

[image: google chrome]

Comment: It's not clear what changed. Can you try and add more details and also get a better screenshot for the 2nd example? It's tiny and hard to even make it out, let alone any diffs. b/w it and the 1st window.

Comment: The only difference I see is that the top Chrome window is maximized and the bottom one isn't. What do you mean by “Windows-XP styled”? I *have* used Windows XP, and I don't see how the top picture relates to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand that correctly you are complaining about the GTK+ theme!? ;-)

Just open the settings of Chromium and click the button "*Classic Theme*" in the "*Appearance*" section. That should turn this silly "*flat 1-D appearance*" into the desired fancy-future-2D look and feel.